# Como passar values de activity para util?

Tags: android

Gostava de trabalhar com o objecto item mas preciso de passar valores da minha actividade para  o util alguem  me consegue explicar?

```
    item[0] = new ColorClothes();
    item[0].record = 0;
    item[0].color = "blue";
    item[0].clothes = "shoes";
```

Por exemplo onde tem "blue" gostaria de estar a receber um valor da minha actividade como seria possível?

```
import java.util.*;


    public class ColorClothes
    {
        public int record;
        public String color;
        public String clothes;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            ColorClothes item[] = new ColorClothes[4];

            item[0] = new ColorClothes();
            item[0].record = 0;
            item[0].color = "blue";
            item[0].clothes = "shoes";

            item[1] = new ColorClothes();
            item[1].record = 1;
            item[1].color = "yellow";
            item[1].clothes = "pants";

            item[2] = new ColorClothes();
            item[2].record = 2;
            item[2].color = "red";
            item[2].clothes = "boots";

            item[3] = new ColorClothes();
            item[3].record = 3;
            item[3].color = "black";
            item[3].clothes = "coat";

            System.out.println("Unsorted");

            for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
            }

            System.out.println("\nSorted By Color\n");

            Arrays.sort(item, new ColorComparator());

            for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
            }

            System.out.println("\nSorted By Clothes\n");

            Arrays.sort(item, new ClothesComparator());

            for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Não entendi direito o que você deseja, você tem um Objeto, com 3 atributos, depois você criar um array desse mesmo objeto e usa ele dentro desse objeto.

Comment: Por exemplo se eu tiver noutra actividade posso usar esse objecto ?

Comment: Bom, essa classe está um pouquinho mal formada para mim, sua intenção com o ´Initialize()` é retornar um array com 4 objetos pré inicializados ?

Comment: sim é isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom Tiago,
Não vejo um bom motivo para tentar instanciar uma classe dentro dela mesma, acredito que o ideal seria você dividir essa classe em duas, sendo uma somente com o Objeto que terá as informações, e uma para fazer essa inicialização, arranjo e etc..

Desta forma, cada "item" terá uma instância separada de dados.

Então, eu faria da seguinte forma:

**ColorClothes:**

```
public class ColorClothes
{

    public ColorClothes() // <------ método construtor
    {
       // O ideal é usar esse método somente para trazer parâmetros iniciais para a instância
    }

    public Clothes[] Initialize(Clothes[] item)
    {
        Clothes item[] = new Clothes[4]; // <----------- utilize o objeto com os dados


        System.out.println("Unsorted");

        for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSorted By Color\n");

        Arrays.sort(item, new ColorComparator());

        for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSorted By Clothes\n");

        Arrays.sort(item, new ClothesComparator());

        for(int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
        }

 return item;

    }


    public class Clothes{
        public int record;
        public String color;
        public String clothes;
   }

    }
```

Na sua **Activity:**

```
Clothes[] listaClothes = new Clothes[4];
            listaClothes [0] = new Clothes();
            listaClothes [0].record = 0;
            listaClothes [0].color = "blue";
            listaClothes [0].clothes = "shoes";
        listaClothes [1] = new Clothes();
        listaClothes [1].record = 1;
        listaClothes [1].color = "yellow";
        listaClothes [1].clothes = "pants";

        listaClothes [2] = new Clothes();
        listaClothes [2].record = 2;
        listaClothes [2].color = "red";
        listaClothes [2].clothes = "boots";

        listaClothes [3] = new Clothes();
        listaClothes [3].record = 3;
        listaClothes [3].color = "black";
        listaClothes [3].clothes = "coat";



ColorClothes colorClothes = new ColorClothes();    
Clothes[] listaOrganizada= colorClothes.Initialize(listaCloth);
```

Pronto, você terá na sua activity o Objeto que era o "item", contendo os 4 objetos.

Comment: O objectivo era o inverso era colocar lá os objectos em vex de retirar eu não sei como manipular o código para isso

Comment: Você quer colocar 4 objetos e retornar eles organizados é isso ?

Comment: Mas o valores estão fixados no Initialize

Comment: Sim desde já obrigado

Comment: É a minha primeira vez usando util se achar que initialize não é necessário para o pretendido pode retirar estou tentanto aprender a sortear multiplos arrays de uma actividade que sao enviados para ai para o util

Comment: o Util é a biblioteca que organiza, não tem a ver com o modo de construir a classe, posso alterar para um método em  que você receba um array e retorne ele no final organizado, os dados normalmente são mutáveis, então você tem que atribuir os valores na Activity, que é o mais usual

Comment: É exactamente isso que procuro e obrigado pela explicação